# Не устанавливается ubuntu на lenovo

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Купил ноут lenovo ideapad 330 - 15ARR. И перепробовал установить каждую версию linux, но на всех системах вылетает либо ошибка(как на скрине), либо не работает wi-fi, отсутствует сетевой адаптер, я попробовал скачать и установить с флешки, ubuntu тупо не запустила файл. Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким? то есть возможно как нибудь установить linux на этот ноут или он не поддерживает его в принципе? Процессор - AMD ryzen 5.

[image: скрин 1 при установке]
[image: скрин 2]

Comment: Для борьбы с неработающими сетевыми интерфейсами попробуйте найти,скачать и установить ручками файл с фирмварями для соответствующих устройств. Возможные названия пакетов — `firmware-iwlwifi`, `firmware-realtek` и т.п.

Comment: Куча неизвестных факторов, вы ничего не написали. В биосе нужно сделать дисковый способ **IDE**.Нельзя  ни **AHCI** ни **RAID**. Диск желательно форматнуть под ноль.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, а почему нельзя `ahci`?

Comment: А iso точно не битый? А как на флэшку писал?

Comment: @don Rumata нельзя **AHCI** , установщик не увидит диск. I/O error - говорит прямо об этом.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, а ты уверен, что на буке с последним райзеном (а соответственно и очень новым чипсетом) есть что-то кроме ahci?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать для записи образа приложение Rufus

Comment: насчет биоса посмотрю, там потому что менял только uefi/legacy настройку.

Comment: iso не битый, качал с офф сайта и флешку делал через руфус. И файлы с фирмварями тоже ускачивал. После установки ubuntu отсутствует wi-fi и файлы не запускаются ни в интерфейсе, ни через консоль(